# How can I get class fields through reflection when backing fields are present?

Tags: c#, reflection, custom-attributes, backing-field

I have a simple POCO class, e.g.

```
class C {
  [MyAtrib]
  public int i {get; set;}
  [MyAtrib]  
  public int i2;
}
```

When I call:

```
GetType().GetFields(
  BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

on that class (instance) I can't get the `FieldInfo` for those members that have automatically generated getters/setters (i.e. `int i` above).

Actually, I'm trying to read those custom attributes (`MyAtrib`) and can't do it for those properties that have `{get; set;}`.

Why is that? I'd expect to get both `i` and it's (private) backing field, since `i` is public.

Can I get to `i`'s `MyAtrib` somehow through reflection?

Comment: Those with getters and setters are not fields; they are properties.

Comment: You definitely get the backing field, using BindingFlags.NonPublic is sufficient.  It has an unspeakable name, `<i>k__BackingField`.  The attribute is *not* applied to the backing field, it exists on the property.  Calling GetProperty() is required to retrieve it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get fields right now, but `public int i {get; set;}` is a property.
You need to get properties:

```
// note: properties -> generally public
GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
```